# How to Solve "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got  **Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function**  error when i'm trying to bring the **ID** and store it in variable

Here i got the error => {var topMenu = $('primary-menu');}

```
// Cache selectors
var topMenu = $('primary-menu');
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find('a[href^="#"]'),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });
   // Get the id of the current element
   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";
   // Set/remove active class
   menuItems
     .parent().removeClass("act")
     .end().filter("[href='#"+id+"']").parent().addClass("act");
});​
```

Comment: Have you imported jQuery before your script ?

Comment: it's wordpress website

Comment: Try using `jQuery` instead of `$`, e.x: `jQuery('.primary-menu')`

Comment: If you're using Wordpress then you need to use the `jQuery` keyword instead of `$`. Better still, wrap the code in a document.ready handler and alias the `$` in there: `jQuery($ => { /* your current code here... */ });`

Comment: i tried `,` but still the same problem

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2895/not-defined-using-jquery-in-wordpress

Comment: sounds like something overwrote $

Comment: Also `$('primary-menu')` is almost certainly incorrect; you need either `#primary-menu` or `.primary-menu` depending on how that identifier is used in the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress has its own `jQuery` version which is loaded by default. In order to avoid conflicts you have two options:

1. Use `jQuery` instead of `$` - which means that all custom code should use `jQuery` and not `$`
2. Wrap your custom code in the following code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // here you can use $
    console.log($('.primary-menu'));
});
```

Comment: this is it, and this has been answered here so many times already. Also you can find more information here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/